# PostgreSql 8.3 and 8.4 problem

Tags: debian, postgresql

I have debian lenny with intall postgresql 8.3 and I need update it to 8.4
I have install it from repository deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free
But now I have two postgre servers. Do I need to buckup DB from 8.3 and import it to 8.4?
I tring it but have problem:

- su postgres
- psql -d template1 and get error psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres" it's correct for server postgre 8.3
  How can I login to postgre console in server 8.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check "man pg_wrapper".  All the postgres commands (like psql) are run through this wrapper, so "psql --cluster 8.3/main templat1" would talk to your 8.3 install and "psql --cluster 8.4/main template1" would talk to your 8.4 cluster.

If all your data is in the 8.3 cluster and nothing is in the 8.4 cluster, you may just want to delete the 8.4 cluster and upgrade the 8.3 cluster to 8.4:

```
$ pg_dropcluster 8.4 main
$ pg_upgradecluster 8.3 main
```

It would, of course, be wise to backup both clusters first.